# Trim unprintable characters using python

Tags: python-2.7

I have text content which is coming from different languages like chines, Hebrew and so on. By using google translator API converting the text into 'en'. Here problem is google translator is failing when its identifies some special characters like \x11,\x01(unable to display those characters over here) and dropping that set of records. Please suggest some safest way to do this conversion with out dropping records.

Answer (score 0):

data = ''.join(c for c in data if c.printable)